# How to prove that this series converges uniformly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

I have a series
$$
-\frac{\pi}{12} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\left(3k\pi^2-16\right)\sin{\frac{k\pi}{2}} + 8\pi\cos{\frac{k\pi}{2}}}{\pi^2k^3}\cos{kt}
$$
And I have to use Weierstass test to prove that the series converges uniformly. The problem is that the sines and cosines are really making it hard to simplify the absolute value of the above and compare it to a known convergent series. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Bound it by a constant times $\frac1{k^2}$ and use the Weierstrass M-test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series converges absolutely and uniformly, independently of $t$. We can bound the numerator above by $3k\pi^2 + 16 + 8\pi$, which is in general less than $C k$ for a constant $C$ and entirely independent of $t$.

Then the sum looks like
$$ \sum_k \frac{C}{k^2},$$
which converges absolutely. This gives absolute and uniform convergence by the Weierstrass M test.

Comment: Yes but how did get the numerator to this form? I assume you removed $16\sin{\frac{k\pi}{2}}$, then estimated that the other $\sin$ and $\cos$ can have a maximum value of 1?

Comment: @JamMaster Bound every trig function here above by $1$. Then realize that all remaining constants eventually (rather quickly) are smaller than $k$.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, shouldnt it be $3k\pi^2-16+8\pi$?

Comment: @JamMaster It could be, under the assumption that $k \geq 2$ (which is a fine assumption). I added the $16$ to not think about it, but also to reflect the possibility that $\sin$ could be negative. The reason we can be so lenient is because that small change doesn't affect convergence at all.